# Ubuntu Search showing uninstalled wine applications

Tags: wine, search

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and I uninstalled Hex Workshop.exe and Immunity Debugger.exe from my PC using wine uninstall.exe . Why do I keep getting them as a search result even though they are uninstalled ??? Is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Goto your Home Directory.
Press Ctrl+H to display Hidden Folders
Goto .local 
Goto wine subfolder 
click on Hex workshop and press Shift+Delete.